# debugging a mysterious 508 (Loop Detected) error

Tags: javascript, php, html, http, http-status-codes

I'm getting a server error (508 Loop Detected) although I don't see anything that I think could cause such a loop.

I've done some reading, but couldn't find much information on that and I 
would really appreciate if someone shed some light on it.

the problem is that I can't seem to send a form to a php page because it gets blocked.

this is the error i get after trying to submit the form:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 508
>   (Loop Detected)

i have 2 files:

- mail.php

  ```
  <?php $fname = $_POST['fname']; echo $fname; ?>
  ```
- index.html (js)

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $('form').submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var data = $(this).serialize(),
          url = $(this).prop('action');

          $.post(url, data, function (res) {

              console.log(res);
          });
      });
  });
  ```
- index.html (html)

`<form action="mail.php">
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>`

I just don't see where does it detect an infinite loop in my code.

now here's the kicker: **it works on a different server**. (obviously, not the right one)

some more info:

- the main domain of the server which i'm working on occaisonaly shows this (instead of a regular homepage)

> Resource Limit Is Reached
>
> The website is temporarily unable to service your request as it
>   exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.

I'm guessing server issues, no idea how to solve this. anybody?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give any details of the webserver you are using, how it is setup, and what kind of hosting service you are using (if any)?

Comment: The issue sorted itself out mysteriously, too. thanks though :)